# delete or "fix" Android external library

Tags: android, android-studio

I was trying to edit the internal code of an external library (Custom-Calendar-View, v1.1) to fit it better in my project but I did "something I shouldn't have done" and I can't undo it anymore. How to fix it now? Is there a way to reinstall this library?

Comment: How you have added library add some more detail about it.

Comment: I added it with this code: `compile 'com.github.npanigrahy:Custom-Calendar-View:v1.1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove refrence of library from your project and add

```
compile 'com.github.npanigrahy:Custom-Calendar-View:v1.1'
```

Comment: Do you mean that I must delete the library of my project?

Comment: Yes just remove library reference and add library reference from a gradle